# Javascript replace globally with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have special characters in my XML and i am using Javascript function to replace it. I have found global search to replace in all my tags as.

```
 var res = outputText.replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
```

But i also want to replace `</Product>` tag with `<btn>Click  NOW</btn></Product>`

How can i replace this i am trying like

```
res = res.replace(/</Product>/g,"<btn>Click  NOW</btn></Product>");
```

But it is giving me error `invalid regular expression flag P`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `/` with `\`:

```
res = res.replace(/<\/Product>/g,"<btn>Click  NOW</btn></Product>"); 
//------------------^
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to scape the / before the P

```
/<\/P
```

Comment: You have to have a line break so the formatting will kick in.

Comment: Thanks. It took me some try&error tests to figure it out, hehe